# Configuring HandlerInterceptors within a @Configuration context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `@Configuration` in Spring 3.0.6 to use dependency injection without using `.xml` definition files.

I use a mixed approach for defining Controllers, I put them in the `DispatcherServlet`'s `@Configuration`, using `@Bean("/sample/path")` *and* use `@RequestMapping` in their methods to further refine the mapping (including using it to append to the bean's path).

This works fairly well with the default HandlerMapper configuration.

Now, I want to add some `HandlerInterceptors` to the mix. It seems that I need to duplicate the default `HandlerMapper` configuration and then add my `HandlerInterceptor`.

However, this does not seem a great idea. Is there any way to add my HandlerInterceptor to the default `HandlerMapper` config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "default HandlerMapper confgiuration" do you mean declaring a BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping and a DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping beans and then setting their "interceptors" properties? In which case I don't see a lot of duplication.

An alternative would be to declare a bean of type MappedInterceptor. It is detected by type and applied to all incoming requests or limited by path patterns.

Comment: Cool! MappedInterceptor is not mentioned in the reference manual!